# Градиент от градиента функции в Python

Tags: python, numpy, градиент

Имеетя поле U, представленное в виде трёхмерного массива m*n*k.
Подскажите, как в Python посчитать следующее выражение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где k - массив коэффициентов такой же размерности, как и U.

Очевидно, что на выходе должен получиться массив размера m*n*k, т.к. двойной градиент преобразуется в лапласиан:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Применение дважды метода `np.gradient(k*np.gradient(U))` не даёт нужного результата, т.к. не понимает этого и продолжает работать с вектором градиента как с массивом поля, просто большей размерности.

Comment: Уточните, вам нужно дважды взять оператор Лапласа, или у вас ошибка в первой формуле? Может быть, там вместо оператора `\Delta` должен стоять оператор `\nabla`?

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, торопился и перепутал значки

Comment: Если поле в виде массива, то используйте scipy.ndimage.filters.laplace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас в первой формуле вашего вопроса ошибка, и вместо двукратного оператора Лапласа там стоит двукратная набла (оператор градиента), то вашу формулу можно упростить вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для градиента есть встроенная функция, для скалярного произведения тоже. Вам остаётся только вычислить оператор Лапласа. Для этого нужно вручную вычислить градиент от каждого компонента градиента и взять из результата соответствующую производную.

```
def laplacian(f, dx):
    """
    Вычисляет значение оператора Лапласа на сетке.
    
    f - значения функции в n-мерной сетке.
    dx - кортеж, элементы кортежа есть шаги сетки.
    """
    result = np.zeros_like(f)
    g = np.gradient(f, *dx, edge_order=2)
    for i, g_i in enumerate(g):
        gg_i = np.gradient(g_i, *dx, edge_order=2)
        result += gg_i[i]
    return result
```

Для примера вычислим оператор Лапласа вручную и функцией `laplacian`. В качестве подопытной свинки будет функция [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import numpy as np
# Сетка
dx = 0.01
X,Y,Z = np.mgrid[-1:1:dx,-1:1:dx,-1:1:dx]
# подопытная функция
F = np.exp(-(X*X+2*Y*Y+3*Z*Z))
# Производные
dFdx = -2*X*F
d2Fdx2 = F*(4*X*X-2)

dFdy = -4*Y*F
d2Fdy2 = F*(16*Y*Y - 4)

dFdz = -6*Z*F
d2Fdz2 = F*(36*Z*Z - 6)
# Лапласиан
L_manual = d2Fdx2 + d2Fdy2 + d2Fdz2
L_computed = laplacian(F, (dx,dx,dx))

# среднеквадратичное отклонение вычисленного от точного
print(np.std(L_manual - L_computed))
```

Результат `0.0026064524156072335`

В основном ошибка набирается по краям. Если отбросить полосу вдоль краёв сетки, то ошибка уменьшается в два раза: `np.std(L_manual[3:-3,3:-3,3:-3] - L_computed[3:-3,3:-3,3:-3])` -> `0.0011257917625283698`

Comment: Большое спасибо!